# Network share over internet from one host to another

Tags: linux, share, network-protocols, samba, nfs

Maybe it's a silly question or bad idea, but I want to realize it.
I need to share my drives from one host(Linux) to another over Internet and mount on dest host.

Both computers using different ISP's and under NAT(router).
Source host is Linux.
Dest host is Windows\Mac.

1st I tired NFS:
I opened 111 and 2049 on source PC to dest host on router. FS's were exported to dest host.
It didn't work. I guess, NFS is designed only for local networks.

2nd was SAMBA:
In configuration I commented under global section 
network/hosts-related lines to make the shares open for all.
Ports 139 and 445 were opened, but no luck. Servers were not pingable during test, I don't know if it's important.

If you have any solutions,comments or suggestions to use other protocols, please reply.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did not hear about storage share over Internet, because the network flow and strategies are not controlled by you. Too many things are uncontrollable, if you really want to do that, I think you should confirm the below things before you do that:

```
1. Does the two host have individual Internet IP address? The two host should be pingable interactively.
2. Are the ports opened for the specific port you want to use? and also the firewall(hardware or software) allow the ports to go through. You can verify this by **telnet** command. `telnet host port`
```

In my opinion, both NFS and SAMBA work in application layer, they can work locally, and through Internet. But when in Internet, many things can not be controlled by ourselves in the network layer. And it is also not safe when used in Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Both host do have individual IP's but not pingable. telnet was working for mentioned hosts in both directions. Yes I understand this could work slow or maybe won't work at all. I guess I need to find some NAS solution, but it would cost quite some money